# Could these humanoids properly clothe themselves?

Tags: humanoid, clothing

The humanoids are quite uniquely shaped: They have a single leg in the middle of their pelvis, which is flexible like a snake or tentacle. They are also facultative unipeds; they can move either on just their foot, or on all three limbs. They hop when going upright, and walk when on all threes

[image: The Anatomy, Standing Tripedally]

Their clothing must cover their genitals (which are at the base of the leg, on the belly side) and nipples, and would have to stay on and cover them as they stand and move both tripedally and unipedally

Is there any way to make clothing that would fit these criteria?

Comment: That's not a humanoid. The definition of a humanoid is one that mostly follows the human body plan.

Comment: I believe it needs 2 arms, a torso, a head, and 2 legs to meet humanoid.

Comment: i don't see a problem with single-legged pants, in combination with a common t-shirt

Comment: @Separatrix It does have many 'humanoid' traits. The leg points directly against the spine, the shoulder joint is extended from the body, and they can stand upright

Comment: @IchthysKing by that approach, just about all mammals are humanoid, many can stand upright on their back legs. Humanoid is quite a tight restriction that basically says if you want to use the species in StarTrek all you need is an actor with some latex gloves, facial prosthetics and a distinctive style of clothing.

Comment: What's the technology level? Do they have synthetics?

Comment: What's the climate?

Comment: Are we about to get another one of your another-version-of-the-first-question series of questions? All this creature need do to clothe itself is *sit down.* I suspect that will be the answer for 2/3 of the questions you're about to ask.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @IchthysKing The title makes it sound like you're asking if the creature would be capable of the physical movements needed to put on clothing, when you're actually asking if it would be possible to design clothes that cover the creature and which they could move freely in. "Clothe themselves" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That foot looks awkward**

First a note about the above body shape: it would need eyes in the back of its head. Even when this one would descend from merfolk returning to land, there's a design issue. The foot is in the opposite direction i.r.t. the hands. In upward position, it could *jump backward* very effectively, but in general, animals won't jump in a direction they don't look.. When it would move forward like you show, the claw has no purpose, for the same reason (sight). How could that foot *ever* have developed ?

**Stockings or jeans, shoes on the "hands"**

Make sure it fits, you don't have knees. I'd say stockings, or tight jeans  would fit, a belt would not be needed. Gloves on the hands, or *shoes* when it is tripedal, as you show..

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3):

### Unitard, leggings etc.

Close fitting gymnastic clothing is your best starting point

The gymnastic movement they have should be matched by an equivalent style of clothing. It has to move with them, flex and stretch as required, while not dragging on the floor in tripod form.

*Of course that's for the common people.*

The wealthy and fashionable will fundamentally not want such practical clothing. I would expect togas and robes, skirts and dresses. Outfits that specifically prohibit the use of what is going to be their most practical and fastest form of locomotion. High fashion will limit movement to their slowest and least practical mode, this is a simple way to demonstrate wealth and privilege.